# Identifying unspliced pass-through wires in a receptacle box

Tags: wiring

I have existing 1/2" emt conduit servicing 20 amp receptacles connected to a single pole 20 amp breaker.  So there are 3 12G wires, 1 black, 1 white and 1 green in the existing conduit.

I'd like to add a single 240V 20 amp receptacle in a separate box at the end of this conduit run, by running  black and red 12g wires back to a separate 20 amp double pole breaker.  These wires will pass through unbroken through each box.  Can I just mark the 2nd black wire with say, brown tape to keep it identified?  Or does the 2nd black wire need to be a different color, say brown?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to do anything to identify the conductors. However, you'll have to worry about box fill, as these conductors will have to be counted in the fill calculation.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 3 Wiring Methods
>
> #### Article 314 Outlet, Device, Pull, and Junction Boxes; Conduit Bodies; Fittings, and Handhole Enclosures
>
> **314.16 Number of Conductors in Outlet, Device, and
>   Junction Boxes, and Conduit Bodies.**
>
> **(B) Box Fill Calculations.**
>
> **(1) Conductor Fill.** Each conductor that originates outside
>   the box and terminates or is spliced within the box shall be
>   counted once, and ***each conductor that passes through the
>   box without splice or termination shall be counted once.***
>   Each loop or coil of unbroken conductor not less than twice
>   the minimum length required for free conductors in 300.14
>   shall be counted twice. The conductor fill shall be calculated
>   using Table 314.16(B). A conductor, no part of which
>   leaves the box, shall not be counted.